# Can a WF/WCF 4.0 service be accessed from 3.5 SP1 clients/websites?

Tags: .net, wcf, workflow-foundation

If I was to develop a workflow hosted in WCF using .NET 4.0, is there anything that will prevent me from accessing it using a 3.5 SP1 based client or website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SOAP, there should be no problems at all. I suppose that if you were using binary, or one of the proprietary transport protocols, you might hit a breaking change.

If you do, then report it to Microsoft using Connect.